# How to do the SharePoint development in Visual Studio Express version

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, visual-studio

As per the various blogs VSTO is not supported in Visual Studio Express. For VSTO you needed the Ultimate, Premium, or Professional versions.

So Is there any possibility or any work around available for SharePoint development from Visual Studio Express ?

Comment: Which Visual Studio are you using like is it 2012 or 2013?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with express edition. You need the higher version of all the SharePoint built-in templates will be prebuilt in those. Otherwise, you have to write the complete code.

I read somewhere you can use the 2013 or 2015 community edition. [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/114a4246-37d2-4872-9ca2-f06fd51fbe10/sharepoint-2013-can-i-use-visual-studio-2012-express-edition-for-webparts-and-app-parts?forum=sharepointdevelopment)